Python не закрывает консоль при выходе из системы, как закрыть консоль после завершения
Всем здравствуйте! Программа на создание пустого окна pygame. Почему то при попытке закрыть это окно ( нажатием на крестик) оно не закрывается, закрыть возможно только принудительно. Почему так происходит и как это исправить? Код прилагаю.
class AlienInvasion:
    'класс для управления ресурсами и поведением игры'
    def __init__(self):
        "инициализирует игру и создает игровые ресурсы"
        pygame.init()
    
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.bg_color = (245, 234, 231)
        
    def run_game(self):
        " запуск основного цикла"
        while True:
        # отслеживание событий клавиатуры и мыши
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    exit()
        # отображение последнего прорисованного экрана 
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            pygame.display.flip()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # создание экземпляра и запуск игры
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()


Вместо exit() используйте pygame.quit(). Если не сработает, то сначала pygame.display.quit(), а затем  pygame.quit().
